# "invalid parameter" error in android

Tags: android, error-handling, http-post

i am trying to upload a file in Php server.the server accepts a request containing Userid,password and a video file.

following is server side code.

```
public function uploadVideoAction(Request $request) {
  $tranlator = $this->get('translator');
  $sUserName = $request->request->get('username');
  $passWord  = $request->request->get('password');
  if(empty($sUserName) || empty($passWord) || empty($_FILES['video_profile_candidate'])) {
            $view = View::create()
                    ->setStatusCode(400)
                    ->setData(array(
                        'message' => $tranlator->trans('Invalid parameters')
                    ));
            return $this->get('fos_rest.view_handler')->handle($view);
  }
```

when ever i am trying to send the request from android through HttpPost getting an "invalid Parameter" error. can anyone help me out.

here is my android code

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        try
             {
              jsonObject.put(CommonString.LOGIN_USER_NAME,"username");
              jsonObject.put(CommonString.LOGIN_PASSWORD,"####");
              System.out.println("object "+jsonObject);
    }
             catch (JSONException e)
    {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }

     HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost("url");
        Log.i(TAG, "request :url");
        httpost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-urlendcode");       
        File file = new File(CommonString.PATH+File.separator+CommonString.VIDEO_SEND_NAME);


        if(file.exists())
        {
         System.out.println("File path "+file.getAbsolutePath());
        }

        try 
        {       
         FileBody filebody=new FileBody(file);
            MultipartEntity multipartEntity = new MultipartEntity();
            multipartEntity.addPart("'password", new StringBody("password"));
            multipartEntity.addPart("'username", new StringBody("username"));
            multipartEntity.addPart("'video_profile_candidate", filebody);
            httpost.setEntity(multipartEntity);

         HttpResponse httpresponse = httpClient.execute(httpost);

         System.out.println("Hiii "+ httpresponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
         Log.i(TAG, "request"+ httpresponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
         Log.i(TAG, "Exception "+e.getMessage());
         System.out.println("Exception "+e.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println("text "+response);
```

Comment: should i need to sent user name & password through MultipartEntity ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about "application/x-www-urlendcode".
Maybe "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"?